# I want to use sprintf to generate a txt file

Tags: c, linux, string, printf

How can I solve this problem?

I want to get information using system function and make this to a text file.
I don't know how to get values and use them in another function.

Furthermore: is it right to use `sprintf` to use the result as a value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char date;
char cpu_rate;
char mem_rate;
char value[500];

void printSystem()
{
    date = system("date");
    cpu_rate = system("top  -bn1| grep -Po '[0-9.]+ id'|head -n1|awk '{print sprintf(\"cpu usage: %.2f%\",100-$1)}'");
    mem_rate = system("top -bn1|grep \"KiB Mem\"| awk '{print sprintf(\"memory usage: %.2f%\",$8/$4*100)}'");
}

char strMK(){
    char* date;
    char* cpu_rate;
    char* mem_rate;

    printSystem();

    sprintf(value, date, cpu_rate, mem_rate);
    printf("%s\n",value);
}

void main(){
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen("mk.txt","w");

    if( fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("FILE OPEN ERROR");
        exit(0);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "%s\n",value);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: *i don't know how to get values and use them in another function* -- You should know that this is really not the right place to learn C basics.

Comment: It could be, but the second argument for `sprintf` should a format string, as with `fprintf` and as with the first argument for `printf`.

Comment: If your goal is to return values from ```printSystem``` function, you have to pass ```date```, ```cpu_rate``` and ```mem_rate``` as pointers to this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect output of the command in the system function to a file. For example,

```
system ("command > file1");
```

If you wish, you can read this file in the program. Using this approach, your program becomes,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char date;
char cpu_rate;
char mem_rate;
char value[500];

void printSystem()
{
    date = system("date > x");
    cpu_rate = system("top  -bn1| grep -Po '[0-9.]+ id'|head -n1|awk '{print sprintf(\"cpu usage: %.2f%\",100-$1)}' > y");
    mem_rate = system("top -bn1|grep \"KiB Mem\"| awk '{print sprintf(\"memory usage: %.2f%\",$8/$4*100)}' > z");
}

char strMK(){
    char* date;
    char* cpu_rate;
    char* mem_rate;

    printSystem();

/*    sprintf(value, date, cpu_rate, mem_rate);
    printf("%s\n",value);  */
}

void main(){
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen("mk.txt","w");

    if( fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("FILE OPEN ERROR");
        exit(0);
    }

    strMK ();
    // fprintf(fp, "%s\n",value);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

And it executes as,

```
$ gcc try.c -o try
$ ./try
$ cat x
Mon May 18 17:15:31 IST 2020
$ cat y
cpu usage: 16.10%
$ cat z
memory usage: 19.24%
```